# Trouble reshaping my data for daily time series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reshape

I have a dataset that contains data collected every minute from November 1 to November 15.  The time is a column, starting at `11/1/2016 00:00:00` and finishing at `11/15/2016 23:59:59  I am trying to reshape this dataset, so that each minute is a column, and each day is a row.  So`[row 1,column 1]`would have the data at 12:00 on 11/1, and`[row 2,column 1]` would have the data at 12:00 on 11/2, ans so on.  Currently, my dataset

I am trying to use the reshape function, and if I check the values, they're not matching up correctly.  In my code, Column 2 of `myData` is the data that I need to reshape, and I have 1440 columns because that's the number of minutes in a day.  And 15 rows, because that's the number of days that I have in my dataset.

Any idea where I could be going wrong?

```
myData = pd.read_csv("Nov1-15.csv")
myData = [myData.iloc[:,2]]
myData = np.asarray(myData)
myData = np.reshape(myData, (1440,15))
myData = np.transpose(myData)
```

My array, after reshape, currently looks like the following:

```
array([[ 137.,  138.,  136., ...,  345.,  614.,  337.],
       [ 137.,  137.,  138., ...,  340.,  611.,  337.],
       [ 138.,  136.,  138., ...,  373.,  611.,  336.],
       ..., 
       [ 137.,  138.,  409., ...,  615.,  336.,  214.],
       [ 136.,  136.,  412., ...,  614.,  334.,  214.],
       [ 138.,  136.,  411., ...,  617.,  339.,  215.]])
```

My original dataset looks like the following, after I read it in from the csv and isolate the second column:

```
[0        137.0
 1        137.0
 2        138.0
 3        137.0
 4        136.0
 5        138.0
 6        137.0
 7        141.0
 8        137.0
 9        139.0
 10       136.0
 11       136.0
 12       137.0
 13       136.0
 14       138.0
 15       138.0
 16       137.0
 17       136.0
 18       138.0
 19       137.0
 20       137.0
 21       138.0
 22       138.0
 23       137.0
 24       135.0
 25       138.0
 26       138.0
 27       138.0
 28       136.0
 29       136.0
          ...  
 21570    614.0
 21571    611.0
 21572    611.0
 21573    611.0
 21574    610.0
 21575    570.0
 21576    346.0
 21577    341.0
 21578    337.0
 21579    337.0
 21580    336.0
 21581    337.0
 21582    336.0
 21583    334.0
 21584    339.0
 21585    337.0
 21586    337.0
 21587    336.0
 21588    238.0
 21589    222.0
 21590    222.0
 21591    220.0
 21592    217.0
 21593    217.0
 21594    214.0
 21595    214.0
 21596    278.0
 21597    214.0
 21598    214.0
 21599    215.0
```

Sample data:

```
11/1/2016 0:00      213
11/1/2016 0:01      214
11/1/2016 0:02      213
11/1/2016 0:03      213
11/1/2016 0:04      210
11/1/2016 0:05      210
11/1/2016 0:06      209
11/1/2016 0:07      209
```

Comment: Can you post a sample (3-5 rows) of your original CSV file? Do you have a `timestamp` column?

Comment: I added some sample data.  And I do have a timestamp column in the format as I included in the sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reshaping:

try to change:

```
myData = np.reshape(myData, (1440,15))
```

to:

```
myData = np.reshape(myData, (15, 1440))
```

Demo:

3 rows, 4 columns:

```
In [333]: np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
Out[333]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

4 rows, 3 columns:

```
In [334]: np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
Out[334]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

**Pandas solution:**

use [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) method, if you don't have lags (missing minutes of data):

```
In [48]: df
Out[48]:
                   ts  val
0 2016-11-16 00:00:00  213
1 2016-11-16 00:01:00  214
2 2016-11-16 00:02:00  213
3 2016-11-16 00:03:00  213
4 2016-11-16 00:04:00  210
5 2016-11-16 00:05:00  210
6 2016-11-16 00:06:00  209
7 2016-11-16 00:07:00  209

In [50]: df.assign(d=df.ts.dt.date, m=df.ts.dt.minute) \
           .pivot(index='d', columns='m', values='val')
Out[50]:
m             0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
d
2016-11-16  213  214  213  213  210  210  209  209
```

otherwise use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method:

```
In [52]: df.assign(d=df.ts.dt.date, m=df.ts.dt.minute) \
           .pivot_table(index='d', columns='m', values='val', aggfunc='mean', fill_value=0)
Out[52]:
m             0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
d
2016-11-16  213  214  213  213  210  210  209  209
```